# Get "Value can't be converted to integer" with gdb in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb

I'm trying this simple assembly program (AT&T syntax) in 64 bit just to try the gas assembler, linker, and so.

```
.section .data

values:
    .int 10, 20

.section .text

.globl _start

_start:

    nop

    mov values, %rax

    movq $1, %rax
    movq $0, %rbx
    int $0x80
```

All assemble, link and seem to work well. In gdb I can view the first value (10) in the rax register with the "info register" command. But when I try to print the content of the first element of "values" with "x/d" I get this message:

```
(gdb) x/d $values
Value can't be converted to integer.
```

Is this a bug from gdb?

Comment: `values` is a memory reference. Use `x/d &values` PS: do not use the `int 0x80` in 64 bit code.

Comment: I absolutely don't believe I did a so stupid mistake! Ok, right, I will use syscall.

Comment: `syscall` but calling convention and function numbers are different too.

Comment: Yes, I have the specs. Thanks for the cue!